# Testing saves data in database

Tags: mysql, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Hi I am trying to run mocha and chai test to test my node js router, which saves a user in mysql database and then returns the same array back.

The problem I am facing at the moment is that I would not like to save the information in the database when I run it from local and when I use a continious integration software like travis/Ci the test fails since there is no database connection. I would like to know how can I test the database saving with the current without actually saving to the database.

Basically meaning having a fake virtual database to save or returning save.

I read that sinon.js can help but I am quite not sure on how to use it.

Here is my code

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var faker = require('faker');
const request = require('supertest');
const should = require('should');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const helper = require('../../models/user');

describe('POST /saveUser',()=>{
    it('should save a new user',(done)=>{
        var fake =
        request(app)
            .post('/saveUser')
            .send({
                Owner : faker.random.number(),
                firstname : faker.name.firstName(),
                lastname : faker.name.lastName(),
                email:faker.internet.email(),
                password : faker.random.number(),
                token : faker.random.uuid()
            })
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res)=>{
                expect(res.body.firstname).to.be.a("string");
                expect(res.body.lastname).to.be.a("string");
                expect(res.body.Owner).to.be.a("number");
            })
            .end(done);
    });
});
```

This is the router

```
router.post('/saveUser',(req,res,next)=>{
   saveUser(req.body).then((result)=>{
        return res.send(req.body);
    }).catch((e)=>{
       return res.send('All info not saved');
   });
});
```

And here is the model

```
saveUser = (userinfo) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    db.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?',userinfo,function(error,results,fields){
        if(error){
            reject();
        }else{
            resolve(userinfo);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a stub. With sinon you can stub methods and call fake methods instead like this:

```
sinon.stub(/* module that implements saveUser */, 'saveUser').callsFake(() => Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, what do you mean by module that implements saveUser, can you please use my codes with your comment, I am new to this and its hard to comprehend.

Comment: Your saveUser method is implemented in some file, in models/user I guess? You have to export saveUser in that file and then you can stub: sinon.stub(helper, 'saveUser')

Comment: so basically something like this
const {saveUser} = require('../../models/user');
sinon.stub(saveUser, 'saveUser').callsFake(() => Promise.resolve());

Comment: const helper = require('../../models/user'); sinon.stub(helper, 'saveUser').callsFake(() => Promise.resolve()); First argument of stub is the object and second the property, in this case the function name.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow and let you know, its pretty damn late in Finland :D 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am getting this error
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, e
nsure it resolves.